# Unable to change size of ListView items

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to change the height of my ListView items. Unfortunately, my ListView Adapter resizes my items to the size of the images loaded into it.

I got my ArrayList from my MainActivity. Here is my ListAdapter:

```
public class Customlist extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactlist;

    public Customlist(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactlist) {
        super(context, R.layout.model, contactlist);
        this.context = context;
        this.contactlist= contactlist;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.namelist);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagelist);

        // Contact
        HashMap<String, String> contact = contactlist.get(position);

        String name = contact.get("name");
        String imageurl = contact.get("imageurl");

        txtTitle.setText(name);
        Picasso.with(context).load(imageurl).into(imageView);

        return rowView;
    }

}
```

And here is my Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagelist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/logoooo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/namelist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:text="Neuraum "
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try "rowView.getLayoutParams().height = YOUR_HEIGHT;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you getView method after

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, parent, true);
```

add this:

```
rowView.getLayoutParams().height = 100; // or whatever you want for your height
```

*UPDATE*
change this

```
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, null, true);
```

to this

```
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, parent, true);
```

and this

```
if (rowView != null){
    rowView.getLayoutParams().height = 100; // or whatever you want for your height
}
```

Comment: : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: , PID: 6308
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.height' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.model, null, true);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,1000);
rowView.setLayoutParams(params);

// ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,height);
```

Comment: Doesnt work as well i got the same error message like i mentioned before

Comment: can you show the error full logcat , it has to work check this out http://imgur.com/a/qGMzG

Comment: Here is my Logcat:

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.hartl.pxp, PID: 22500
                                                                       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.hartl.pxp.Locations.Customlist.getView(Customlist.java:37)